# Library Size and Method Counts

Tags: android, methods, android-appcompat

While developing an Android Library, if I add v7 Support Library as an dependency to use Toolbar class only, then would the final .aar file contain only the methods of Toolbar class and the related classes only, or it will contain that of Entire Support Library which wouldn't be in any use?

Comment: Do you add it as gradle dependency?

Comment: yes. In <library name>/build.gradle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'll contain the entire support library. In order to remove the unused classes and methods you should use ProGuard. Check out the [official guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html)
about code and resource shrinking.

Comment: And how are the proguard rules going to look like...?

Comment: Actually he is talking about library, so best solution would be just to stay it as dependency, in order library users will get dependency of that library by there own. It's bad idea to include support library code inside library.

Comment: The ProGuard rules depend on what library are you using, because there are many things like reflection that you should note (e.g. if a library is using reflection on the "A" class, then you shouldn't obfuscate the methods or classes called by reflection for example).

Comment: In such case, should i use 'provided' in dependencies?

Comment: Provided means that the support library won't be the part of my library but it has to be in the application.

Comment: I think that is OK as far as the library classes and methods you're calling doesn't change (that should be the case of the public methods of the Android Support Library).

Answer (score 0):

It will be completely included in your aar. In order to do it in right you you should use `provided`, e.g.:

```
provided 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
```

In that case users of your library will use there own support library and will not have the same code of support library which will go with your lib.

Comment: This answer can be accepted, though it might affect the size of the application...

Comment: @AngadSingh yes, affect in a good way. Your library will be smaller and will not cause of duplication of same code in projects which will use your library.